# Does FIDE have rules governing online chess?

Tags: rules, fide, online-chess

FIDE has its [Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012018) which have governed over-the-board chess for almost 100 years. During the Covid pandemic OTB chess has almost stopped in many countries and more and more chess is being played at a serious level online.

Some federations, which have had to cancel their regular national championships, have replaced them with an online version. Example - the English Chess Federation. Their [online national championships](https://www.englishchess.org.uk/british-online-chess-championships/) have just finished with Micky Adams winning the first place playoff.

Does FIDE have regulations for online chess which can be used as a standard by the member federations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [an announcement](https://fide.com/news/889) on the FIDE website today, 4th January 2021,

> The FIDE Council has approved a new set of rules to be applied to official online chess competitions. The document, which will be incorporated into the laws of chess, is the result of a joint effort by a dedicated task force, in which several FIDE Commissions were involved

According to Article 1 of the new [FIDE Online Chess Regulations](https://www.fide.com/docs/regulations/Annex_6.4%20Fide%20Online%20Chess%20Regulations.pdf) they build on the existing FIDE Laws of Chess:

> **Article 1: Application of the FIDE Laws of Chess**
>
> 1.1 Articles 1 – 3 of the Basic rules of play from the FIDE Laws of Chess are fully applied, except Article 2.1.
>
> 1.2 Article 2.1 of the Basic rules of play from the FIDE Laws of Chess is superseded by Article 3.1 of
> these Regulations.
>
> 1.3 Articles 4 and 5 of the Basic rules of play from the FIDE Laws of Chess are superseded by Articles 3 and 5 of these Regulations respectively

The new Article 3 deals with the mechanics of moving the pieces in online chess and so covers things like pre-moves and auto promotion.

The new Article 5 on completing the game is particularly interesting as it changes the repetition and 50/75 move rule to reflect the way online platforms currently operate. Here is what it says:

> **Article 5: Completing the Game**
> 5.1 The game is won by the player who has checkmated **his/her** opponent’s king.
> 5.2 The game is won by the player whose opponent declares **he/she** resigns by pressing button “resign” or
> by another method available on the playing zone.
> 5.3 The player can offer a draw in accordance with any method provided by the playing zone. The offer cannot be withdrawn and remains valid until the opponent accepts it, rejects it by playing a
> move or the game is concluded in some other way.
> 5.4 **The game is automatically drawn when**:
> 5.4.1 **the same position appeared for the third time** (as described in Article 9.2.2 of the FIDE Laws of Chess);
> 5.4.2 the player to move has no legal move and his/her king is not in check. The game is said to end in
> ‘stalemate’;
> 5.4.3 a position has arisen in which neither player can checkmate the opponent’s king with any series of legal moves;
> 5.4.4 **the last 50 moves by each player have been completed without the movement of any pawn and without any capture.**

There is much more,including rules covering disconnection, and it is worth examining in detail. I have to admit that, although I'm a non-smoker myself, I find article 9.9 over-authoritarian -

> 9.9 Smoking, including e-cigarettes, is not permitted when visible on camera.

There is, quite rightly, nothing about eating or drinking on camera. FIDE should not be legislating on other non-disturbing behaviour in players' own homes.

Finally it is noteworthy that FIDE has adopted the more inclusive he/she, his/her